# TCPDF - How can I stop function file_exists in php from interfering with browser cache?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, tcpdf

I have a button "print" , when it's clicked I send an `AJAX` request to my php script.

request contains : 
Filename
other data.

I generate a pdf with this script Using `TCPDF` and return the link to the file to my ajax request.

Inside my `PHP` script :

I first test if the fileName sent exists in the folder where I keep all pdf files, if it existes I "`UNLINK`" it , if not I proceed with my script.

The problem I have is that whenever I make a change in the data I send to the script , the same pdf is created ( first one ) , so I assume it is a problem with the cache , and as I searched a bit , I found that the function `file_exits` has something to do with it ?

Any taughts on this issue  ?  or maybe a solution ?

I can provide any piece of code you want to help understant the issue.

EDIT:

my file_exits on php script :

```
 if (file_exists('../store_files/'.$_POST["pdf_name"].'.pdf')) {
        unlink('../store_files/'.$_POST["pdf_name"].'.pdf');
   }
```

and just before the output I use the headers :

```
header ( 'Expires: 0' );header ( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
    $pdf->Output(savepath.'/'.$name_pdf, 'F');
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly to the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) directives.

Comment: It would help if you could update the question to improve it. Also, adding some 'interesting' code snippets would probably be useful.

Comment: @downvoter :  if you need more explanations/code snippets etc ; just ask and i'll provide them , downvoting is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

I think TCPDF is capable of overwriting an existing PDF.  You would not need to use unlink(), and I cannot think of any reason file_exists() would be in play.  It's possible (not sure) that the browser has cached the PDF document.  If that's the case, you might try changing the file name or changing the URL when the document is created, something like /path/to/my.pdf?q=*random*

Comment: I clear the cache of the browser and BOOM , it works , my new pdf is updated with latest data ,  so I am pretty sure that my browser cashes the document,  is there any other solution other than creating a different filename each time ?  because if a lot of users call the script I will end up with an endless amount of files that requires important storage on the server

Comment: @samouray yes there is, add ```header ( 'Expires: 0' );header ( 'Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' );```  before any output to the browser where you serve the pdf

Comment: I found some answers with this particular code and already added it to my php script just before my output , with no result

Comment: "if a lot of users call the script I will end up with an endless amount of files..." I don't think that would be a problem if the app is designed correctly.  If there is customization on a "per user" basis, of course there would be one PDF per user, but if there is no customization and you can serve the same file for all users, you would only need one PDF file.  You might also consider creating the PDF and giving the client a URL link to the PDF, rather than sending the PDF to the browser.  You might also consider a garbage collection strategy to get rid of old files.

Answer (score 1):

in order to make sure that file_exists() actually checks the filesytem, and doesn't return a cached result, run `clearstatcache(true)` first.

btw, have you considered that you might be experiencing a race condition? that several ajax requests are processed at the same time, that generates the same filename, and php#1 does file_exist("foo.pdf") , sees that it doesn't exist, and starts creating it - but at the same time, before its done creating the foo.pdf , php#2 also does file_exist , sees that it doesn't exist, and start creating it - and then php #1 finishes, writes foo.pdf - and then php#2 finishes, tries to write foo.pdf - but notices that it already exists, and doesn't want to overwrite it - and errors out?

Comment: @downvoter , can you please explain why you are downvoting?

Comment: I ran clearstatcache(true) and it's always the same issue, the second part of your answer seems intersting to me , as it could happen in the future when a lot of users send ajax requests at the same time,  but for now I am the only one sending the request and it is only one so I am pretty sure it is not a race condtion problem